# Merge multiple MySQL tables which are related and return JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. But with no luck.

This works, but not what i exactly want

How it's now:

```
{"text":"My first report","comment":"Great Report","display_name":"Xavier"},
{"text":"My First report","comment":"Do you call this a report?","display_name":"Logan"}
```

How I would like it to be:

```
{"text":"My first report","comments":[{comment: "Great Report","display_name":"Xavier"}, {comment: "Do you call this a report?","display_name":"Logan"}],
```

Current Setup

```
Report
ID | User_ID | TEXT |
15 | 3         My first report

Users
ID | DISPLAY_NAME |
1  | Xavier
2  | Logan
3  |  Cyclops
```

How it is now:

```
Report_Comments
ID | User_ID | Report_ID | TEXT as comment |
3  | 1         15          Great Report
3  | 2         15          Bad Report
```

My code:

```
SELECT r.text, 
       Group_concat(r.user_id)      AS User_ID, 
       Group_concat(u.display_name) AS User_Name, 
       r.id, 
       Group_concat(c.text)         AS comment 
FROM   report r 
       LEFT JOIN users u 
              ON u.id = r.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN report_comments c 
              ON c.report_id = r.id 
WHERE  r.user_id = :userId 
GROUP  BY r.id, 
          r.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) and JSON_OBJECT, we can achieve this with only one join.

Recreating your situation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reports (id INT, user_id INT, title VARCHAR(60), PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (id));
CREATE TABLE comments (id INT, user_id INT, report_id INT, comment VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Xavier'), (2, 'Logan'), (3, 'Cyclops');
INSERT INTO reports VALUES (10, 1, 'My First Report');
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (100, 1, 10, 'bad report'), (200, 1, 10, 'good report');
```

We now can run a `SELECT` which joins the tables reports and comments, grouping by the id of reports. Using the `JSON_OBJECT` function we create the JSON document. With the `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, we aggregate into 'comments'.

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('text', r.title, 'comments',
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('comment', c.comment, 'name', u.name))) as report_comments
FROM reports AS r JOIN comments c on r.id = c.report_id
    JOIN users u on c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| report_comments                                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"text": "My First Report", "comments": [{"name": "Xavier", "comment": "bad report"}, {"name": "Logan", "comment": "good report"}]} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Result using JSON_PRETTY and `\G` instead of `;` executing the query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
report_comments: {
  "text": "My First Report",
  "comments": [
    {
      "name": "Xavier",
      "comment": "bad report"
    },
    {
      "name": "Logan",
      "comment": "good report"
    }
  ]
}
```